# Add class to a specific parent element in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

I'm trying to build a small plugin to add a class to a specific tag in CKEditor. Here is what it should do: if the user is creating a list, wherever he is in that list, if he clicks the button, it adds a class to the `ul` parent.

I've managed to detect that tag. But, I can't find how to add a class and mainly, how to apply those changes after. Here is what I have right now:

```
editor = CKEDITOR.replace('editor');

editor.addCommand("testCommand", {
    exec: function(e) {
        parents = e.elementPath();
        parents = parents.elements;

        for (i = 0; i < parents.length; i++) {
            console.log('Check');

            if(parents[i].getName() ==  'ul') {
                console.log('List !');

                return true;
            }
        }
    }
});

editor.ui.addButton('testButton', {
    label: "Test button",
    command: 'testCommand',
    toolbar: 'insert',
    icon: 'Link'
});
```

Could you help?

Comment: Check [addClass](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_dom_element.html#method-addClass). Also, add the classname to the allowed classnames for 'ul' like this: `config.extraAllowedContent = 'ul(myclass)'`

Comment: @Wizard Yes, that's what I was checking. But, all the example I was able to find are with the creation of new elements. Here I want to alter an existing one

Comment: After `console.log('List !');` add `parents[i].addClass('myclass');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q3ryoL1g/5/).

```
CKEDITOR.addCss('ul.myclass { font-weight: bold; }'); // <-- CSS class declaration

const editor = CKEDITOR.replace('editor', {
    toolbar: [
        { name: 'paragraph', items: [ 'Source', 'BulletedList', 'testButton' ] }
    ],
    extraAllowedContent: 'ul(myclass)' // <-- needed for Advanced Content Filtering (ACF)
});

editor.addCommand("testCommand", {
    exec: function(e) {
        let parents = e.elementPath();
        parents = parents.elements;

        for (let i = 0; i < parents.length; i++) {
          console.log('Check');

          if (parents[i].getName() ==  'ul') {
            console.log('Liste !');
            parents[i].addClass('myclass'); // <-- adds the CSS class
            break;
          }
       }
    }
});

editor.ui.addButton('testButton', {
    label: "Test button",
    command: 'testCommand',
    toolbar: 'insert',
    icon: 'Link'
});
```

Comment: Oh ok, it was not clear I could apply this directly to my element. Thanks :)